# Отображение координат chart (полярная)

Tags: c#, wpf, диаграммы

Добрый день, вопрос такой. Есть Chart обычного вида и когда на точку наводится курсор, то отображается плашка с координатами. Создаю Chart полярного типа и там эта плашка не работает. В чем может быть проблема? (Прикрепляю код для обоих chart).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это код для Line chart

```
<c1:C1Chart x:Name="chart_bi_ch_dec" ChartType="LineSmoothed" Palette="Verve" Margin="0">
                            <c1:C1Chart.View>
                                <c1:ChartView>
                                    <c1:ChartView.Layers>
                                        <c1:ChartPanel MouseDown="ChartPanel_MouseDown_3" MouseWheel="ChartPanel_MouseWheel_3" >
                                            <c1:ChartPanelObject x:Name="XYmarker6" DataPoint="0,0"  Action="MouseMove" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Attach="DataXY">
                                                <Border Background="#7F008000" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1,1,3,3" Margin="-1.5,0,0,0" CornerRadius = "6,6,6,0" Padding="3">
                                                    <StackPanel>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Parent.Parent.Parent.DataPoint.X, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, StringFormat=x\=0.00;x\=-0.00}" />
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Parent.Parent.Parent.DataPoint.Y, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, StringFormat=y\=0.00;y\=-0.00}" />
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Border>
                                            </c1:ChartPanelObject>
                                        </c1:ChartPanel>
                                    </c1:ChartView.Layers>
                                    <c1:ChartView.AxisY>
                                        <c1:Axis Title="Эффективная площадь рассеивания, дБм^2"/>
                                    </c1:ChartView.AxisY>
                                    <c1:ChartView.AxisX>
                                        <c1:Axis Name="Title_x_dec_ch_bi" Title="Угол места / Азимут, град." MinorTickThickness="0" FontSize="10" MajorTickThickness="2"/>
                                    </c1:ChartView.AxisX>
                                </c1:ChartView>
                            </c1:C1Chart.View>
                            <c1:C1Chart.Data>
                                <c1:ChartData>
                                    <c1:XYDataSeries  Values="" XValues="" ConnectionFill="#FFF30707" SymbolFill="#FFB8250E"/>
                                </c1:ChartData>
                            </c1:C1Chart.Data>
                        </c1:C1Chart>
```

А вот код для полярного графика

```
                            <c1:C1Chart x:Name="chart_bi_ch_polyar" ChartType="PolarLines" c1:PolarRadarOptions.StartingAngle="0" c1:PolarRadarOptions.Direction="Counterclockwise" >
                            <c1:C1Chart.View>
                                <c1:ChartView>
                                    <c1:ChartView.Layers>
                                        <c1:ChartPanel MouseDown="ChartPanel_MouseDown_4" MouseWheel="ChartPanel_MouseWheel_4" >
                                            <c1:ChartPanelObject x:Name="XYmarker1" DataPoint="0,0"  Action="MouseMove" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Attach="DataXY">
                                                <Border Background="#7F008000" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1,1,3,3" Margin="-1.5,0,0,0" CornerRadius = "6,6,6,0" Padding="3">
                                                    <StackPanel>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Parent.Parent.Parent.DataPoint.X, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, StringFormat=x\=0.00;x\=-0.00}" />
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Parent.Parent.Parent.DataPoint.Y, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, StringFormat=y\=0.00;y\=-0.00}" />
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </Border>
                                            </c1:ChartPanelObject>
                                        </c1:ChartPanel>
                                    </c1:ChartView.Layers>
                                    <c1:ChartView.AxisY>
                                        <c1:Axis Title=""/>
                                    </c1:ChartView.AxisY>
                                    <c1:ChartView.AxisX>
                                        <c1:Axis Title=""  AxisType="Y" MajorUnit="30" MinorUnit="5" MinorGridStroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}" MajorGridStroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}" AnnoFormat="#°">
                                            <c1:Axis.AxisLine>
                                                <Line/>
                                            </c1:Axis.AxisLine>
                                        </c1:Axis>
                                    </c1:ChartView.AxisX>
                                </c1:ChartView>
                            </c1:C1Chart.View>
                            <c1:C1Chart.Data>
                                <c1:ChartData>
                                    <c1:XYDataSeries  Values="" XValues="" ConnectionFill="#FFF30707" SymbolFill="#FFB8250E">
                                        <c1:XYDataSeries.Effect>
                                            <DropShadowEffect/>
                                        </c1:XYDataSeries.Effect>
                                    </c1:XYDataSeries>
                                </c1:ChartData>
                            </c1:C1Chart.Data>
                            <c1:C1ChartLegend Title="Эффективная площадь рассеивания, дБм^2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,6,-16" Position="TopRight" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" Height="42"/>
                        </c1:C1Chart>
```

Comment: Вы выложили два идентичных кода

Comment: Извиняюсь, исправлено.

Comment: А что за `Chart`? Что за namespace c1? Это явно что-то нестандартное.

Comment: ComponentOne C1Chart for WPF DLL

Comment: C1Chart платный :(

Comment: Что значит "эта плашка не работает" ? Покажите `весь` код, который связан с проблемой. Лучше всего создайте MCVE.

Comment: "когда на точку наводится курсор, то отображается плашка с координатами" на первом скриншоте она зеленого цвета. И это и есть весь код. Дело именно в XAML. Код на c# лишь заполняет график точками.